# SSRS Toggle Expand/Collapse using Parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have report which are grouped by Client,Sub Client, Year, Quarter, Month, Date and Day. The group is set-up using Expand and Collapse option. For subscription purposes the report does not work when rendering in .pdf version because it needs to be expanded before rendering in .pdf.

I created a "None-DoNotShow" parameter holding a value of "Expand" or "Collapse"

The code is placed in the group detail visability

```
=iif(Parameters!ParamExpandOrCollapse.Value="Collapse",True,False)
```

The code is placed in InitialToggleState in Client Column

```
=IIF(Parameters!ParamExpandOrCollapse.Value="Expand",True,False)
```

[image]

I found, read and follow the steps in this [article](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html) I found from http://www.sqlchick.com, and it only works on the first grouped column. I'm having difficulty making it worked for the Sub Client, Year, Quarter, Month, Date and Day.

Comment: Are you using a text box to control the Visibility? Each one should have a **different Toggle Item** - your Sub-Client Total line toggle should be based on the client column and your Year would be based on the Sub Client (which has Client as the field).

Comment: Yes. At first I was going to control it by a Boolean parameter. Ok let me try your suggestion. Thanks.